# WordPress as git submodule, accidentally updated through WP admin instead of git, now modified content

Tags: wordpress, git, git-submodules, git-reset

I followed David Winter's workflow to "Install and Manage WordPress with Git." WordPress is a git submodule. On the latest WordPress 3.9 upgrade, I accidentally updated through the WordPress admin instead of via git. Now when I run `git status` I get:

```
modified:   wordpress (modified content, untracked content)
```

Which makes sense. But I can't commit the modified wordpress content. The WordPress submodule is dirty. If I run `git diff` within my main repo, I get this:

```
-Subproject commit 22bb60277036651db73dc872eaa7d2a50276b00d
+Subproject commit 22bb60277036651db73dc872eaa7d2a50276b00d-dirty
```

What's the best way to fix this? If I run the following within my main repo, will it mess up my WordPress install? (Note: I had also updated some plugins.)

```
git clean -dfx             # delete everything in the worktree that isn't tracked
git reset --hard           # wipe all modifications to tracked files
git checkout 3.8.1         # return to previous version tag
```

Update: The commands above work perfectly. I checked the documentation on git clean to learn what the options 'd', 'f', and 'x' were: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html. After I ran the previous commands within the WordPress directory, I was able to then checkout version 3.9, thus correctly updating WordPress.

Comment: You can run those commands in the Wordpress directory since it has its own submodule. It shouldn't affect any of the plugins.  The Wordpress directory should be completely self-contained, so you could also simply delete it and then clone the repository again.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the commands in the WordPress directory and then checked out the 3.9 tag. Everything is clean and resolved now.

Comment: I updated my question to include the resolution.

Comment: @scpers0n Add your update as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The following commands worked perfectly:

```
git clean -dfx             # delete everything in the worktree that isn't tracked
git reset --hard           # wipe all modifications to tracked files
git checkout 3.8.1         # return to previous version tag
```

I checked the documentation on git clean to learn what the options 'd', 'f', and 'x' were: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html. After I ran the previous commands within the WordPress directory, I was able to then checkout version 3.9, thus correctly updating WordPress.